# ROS using template class member as callback for topic subscription

Tags: c++, ros

I'm trying to create a class that can be instantiated once, and to which one can add ros topic subscriptions where the callbacks are template specializations of the same member function.

The class ros_topic_subscriber.h file is

```
class ROSTopicSubscriber
{
public:

    ROSTopicSubscriber() {}

    ~ROSTopicSubscriber() {}

    template<typename ROSMessageType>
    int init
    (
        const ros::NodeHandle &controller_nh,
        const std::string& topic_name,
        unsigned int buffer_size
    )
    {
        ros::Subscriber sub = controller_nh.subscribe(
            topic_name, 
            buffer_size, 
            &ROSTopicSubscriber::topicCallback<ROSMessageType>,
            this
        );
    }

    /*! \brief Implement this function for your own message!
    */
    template<typename ROSMessageType>
    void topicCallback(const typename ROSMessageType::ConstPtr& msg);


private:

    // No copying of this class is allowed !
    ROSTopicSubscriber(const ROSTopicSubscriber& other) = delete;
    ROSTopicSubscriber(ROSTopicSubscriber&& other) = delete;
    ROSTopicSubscriber& operator=(const ROSTopicSubscriber& other) = delete;
    ROSTopicSubscriber& operator=(ROSTopicSubscriber&& other) noexcept = delete;

};
```

and one possible template specialization of topicCallback in my case is (in the ros_topic_subscriber.cpp file)

```
template<>
void ROSTopicSubscriber::topicCallback<geometry_msgs::Pose>
(
    const geometry_msgs::Pose::ConstPtr& msg
)
{
    std::cout << "msg\n";
}
```

and to make use of this class one could for example do

```
topic_subscriber_.init<geometry_msgs::Pose>
    (n, "/wintracker/pose", 100);
```

Now, the compiler error I'm getting is this:

```
ros_topic_subscriber.h:66:3: 
error: passing ‘const ros::NodeHandle’ as ‘this’ argument of 
‘ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(
    const string&, 
    uint32_t, 
    void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&), 
    T*, 
    const ros::TransportHints&) 
[with M = geometry_msgs::Pose_<std::allocator<void> >; 
    T = hiqp::ROSTopicSubscriber; 
    std::string = std::basic_string<char>; 
    uint32_t = unsigned int]’ 
discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

Why does this error message appear in this case? 
Is it possible to implement this kind of class?
How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ROSTopicSubscriber::init` gets the `controller_nh` parameter as a `const` reference which means it can only call methods that are declared as callable on a constant object. However you try to call the `subscribe` method which is not declared in such way.

The method declaration presumably looks like this in your code:

```
class NodeHandle {
    // ...
    Subscriber subscribe(/* all the parameters */);
    // ...
}
```

The solution depends on whether the `subscribe` method needs to change anything inside the `NodeHandle` object or not. If not, then mark it as callable on a constant object:

```
class NodeHandle {
    // ...
    Subscriber subscribe(/* all the parameters */) const; // <- notice const!
    // ...
}
```

If the `subscribe` method changes something inside `NodeHandle`, then instead you need to change the `controller_nh` parameter of `ROSTopicSubscriber::init` method to be a mutable (not constant) reference:

```
int init
(
    ros::NodeHandle &controller_nh, // <- notice const is gone
    const std::string& topic_name,
    unsigned int buffer_size
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I blindly looked at the template related code!